# Adding Woocommerce to my own theme, how do I do it?

Tags: theme-development, plugins

After searching and trying for days, I'm starting to get agitated..

I have a custom theme for Wordpress, wich seems to function OK.
But after installing Woocommerce several widget don't work, such as the shopping cart and lightbox.

I found out that it has something to do with my theme not being compatible with Woocommerce because when I change to a standard theme everything works as expected.

On Woocommerce docs I saw I might have to add some hooks to my functions.php but I can't figure out where to add these hooks...

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: It seems like Woothemes purposely provides bad documentation. I found quite a lot of people having similar problems....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your FTP browser and go to your WordPress root folder. Find `wp-content/themes/` folder, there should be your theme folder and `functions.php` file inside of it. Open `functions.php` file in a text editor application. Add suggested hooks at the bottom of your `functions.php` file and save it.

Comment: When adding the hooks it breaks my responsive css...

Comment: It is another question ;)

Comment: But the widgets still aren't working...